# Definitive ionic install guide

Tags: android, webapp-development

Down vote me to antarctica if you must but I have tried every guide, vm, script to try and get this working but I just can't get it to play ball. What goes wrong? you name it. There are so many dependancies and steps. Has anyone got a definitive guide that works %100 of the time, preferably for ubuntu 14.04.

Error I get

```
ionic run android
Running command:/home/user/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/user/myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/run 
ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

/home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error executing "adb devices": /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

My path ...

```
  echo $PATH
  /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/user/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/user/android-sdk-linux:/home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/user/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/user/android-sdk-linux
```

ionic list

```
  Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
  Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
  Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
  Ionic Version: 1.0.1
  Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
  Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
  OS: Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 
  Node Version: v0.12.6
```

Comment: https://github.com/nraboy/ubuntu-ionic-installer/blob/master/ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh

Comment: That's a start, but I feel, that it won't be enough to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 
Node Version: v0.12.6

Comment: followed this guide word for word http://stackoverflow.com/a/31041813

Comment: if I run the nraboy script I get the following 

ionic run android
Running command: /home/jason/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/jason/myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/jason/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/run 
ANDROID_HOME=/home/jason/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

/home/jason/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error executing "adb devices": /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found

Comment: ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/jason/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project